# Building a parameter string from XML in PHP - where to add the "&" symbol

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, query-string, querystringparameter

I need to build a parameter string and output it.  It should look something like this:
`?name=something&value=orother&type=xyz&....`

I am using the simplexml_load_file() function to load an xml file.  Then I use a foreach loop to build my string:

```
$parameterString = "?";
foreach($xml->app as $app) {
    $parameterString = $parameterString."name=".urlencode($app->name)."&icon=".urlencode($app->icon)."&type=".urlencode($app->type);
}

echo($parameterString);
```

This is all fine so far as it goes except that if the string is to contain more than a single set of parameters, sets after the first do not begin with the "&" character.  I cant simply go ."&" at the end of that line or I get an unwanted "&" at the end of my string.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Define a `boolean variable` which after the first set of parameters will be changed to `true` , use a simple `if` condition inside the loop that will check `if($first)` , `else` use `&`.

Comment: How do you handle multiple 'app' ?? since you always use the same variables names...

Answer (score 2):

PHP has [a function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) called `http_build_query` which will turn an associative array (key-value pairs) into a parameter string. Perhaps using this will make things easier since you can just build an array with the parameters first, then transform it into a properly formatted and escaped output string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.http-build-query.php) to build query string